# Jenkins json REST api does not show failcount, skipCount and totalCount for a console job output

Tags: json, rest, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, dashing

I am planning to use following data in one of my dashboards that I am running on dashing.io framework. Is there any plugin or setting that I am missing in the Jenkins job or server that is restricting it to set this data in Jenkins REST API for particular test?

{
      "failCount" : 1,
      "skipCount" : 0,
      "totalCount" : 62,
      "urlName" : "reportTest"
    },

Answer (score 0):

The following Jenkins-API-page gives you a detailed overview about all tests executed in your build-job if your Jenkins is provided with the [JUnit-Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin):

> https://{jenkins}/job/{jobname}/{jobnr}/testReport/api/json?pretty=true

You can easily use the json-code from that url in your dashing.io-Dashboard if you adapt the [dashing-jenkins-widget](https://github.com/kj187/dashing-jenkins_job) which you can find on github.